# Confusion on Cauchy's Theorem in Gamelin

Tags: complex-analysis

Gamelin states Cauchy's Theorem as follows

> **Theorem (Cauchy's Theorem).** Let $D$ be a bounded domain with piecewise smooth boundary. If $f(z)$ is an analytic function on $D$ that extends smoothly to $\partial D$, then $$\int_{\partial D}f(z)\,dz = 0.$$

However, $f(z) = \frac{1}{z}$ is holomorphic on the punctured plane $\mathbb{C} - \{0\}$, and so it's holomorphic on unit disk punctured at the origin. But a quick computation shows that $$\int_{\mid z = 1\mid} f(z)\, dz = 2\pi i,$$
a contradiction.

Looking up Cauchy's Theorem on Wikipedia, it states the additional assumption (missing from Gamelin) that the domain must be simply-connected. This fixes our issue, since the punctured disk has fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}$. Is this just a typo in Gamelin that he forgot to included simply-connected? I doubt it is, so I'm probably just missing something.

Further, a couple arguments in Gamelin seem to ignore the requirement that $D$ be simply-connected. For example, I remember an argument of the following flavor: say that $g(z)$ is analytic on a disk $D$, except at two distinct points $p, q\in D$ with $\rho(p, q) = \varepsilon > 0$. Let $\delta = \varepsilon/3$. Let $B_\delta(x)$ represent the ball of radius $\delta$ centered at $x$. Choose some positive $\delta < \varepsilon/3$ such that $B_\delta(p)$ and $B_\delta(q)$ are contained in $D$. Now let $D_\delta = D - B_\delta(p) - B_\delta(q)$. Applying Cauchy's Theorem, we get that
$$\int_{\partial D_\delta} g(z) = 0.$$

I don't see how one could apply this argument since $D_\delta$ generally won't be simply-connected.

Comment: Yes, you're right, you need $D$ to be simply connected for Cauchy's theorem. Alternatively you need $f$ to have an antiderivative (which doesn't hold for $f(z) = \frac{1}{z}$ on the punctured plane).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the unit disk punctured at the origin is not a domain with a smooth boundary because a single point (the origin) is not a smooth boundary: you can't map the unit interval $I=[0,1]$ to a single point with a smooth diffeomorphism.

*Note: it would be useful that you mention in the question the definition provided by Gamelin of a domain and a smooth boundary.*

Comment: Domain: "A subset $D$ of the complex plane is a **domain** if $D$ is open and if any two points of $D$ can be connected by a broken line segment in $D$." That is, Gamelin just considers a set a domain if it's open and path-connected. Not sure what he defines as smooth boundary, but in any case, it doesn't affect a disk punctured in the interior, I don't think.

Comment: @FazeZizek *...but in any case, it doesn't affect a disk punctured in the interior, I don't think...* This is true. But it affects the boundary as the origin is part of the boundary.

Comment: @mathcountrexamples.net Oh, of course. I'm a fool. Thank you!

Comment: @FazeZizek : As the origin is part of the boundary, next you can consider that there is no smooth continuation of the function to this part of the boundary.